# Дана таблица с пояснением синтаксиса NAL unit'a. Как её трактовать?

Tags: c++, видео, syntax

Вникаю в стандарт h.265\HEVC, есть таблица, которая должна пояснять синтаксис NAL unit'ов. Но она лишь вызывает вопросы.

[![Вторая таблица, посвящённая header'у NAL unit'а, мне понятна. В ней объясняют строение заголовка юнита, что он состоит из двух байт, и сколько бит выделены под какую часть. Хотя я и не понял, к чему круглые скобки после nal_unit_header. Ибо, как я понял, достаточно создать структуру\класс, включающие в себя составные части.

Но вот первая таблица меня полностью запутала. Nal единица описана как функция, принимающая NumBytesInNalUnit - количество байт в Nal единице. Вот только количество байт в Nal единице нигде не указано. 
В самом стандарте описывается значение отдельных частей кода, но это мне ничего не дало. 
next_bits(n) - она дана тут образно? Ибо такой функции я не нашёл. Как и отдельные элементы, вроде rbsp_byte.
И что это за функция? Как её трактовать? Как выяснить размер NAL unit'ов?
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvx6m.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvx6m.jpg)

[На всякий случай, вот стандарт. Страница 51.](https://www.itu.int/rec/dologin_pub.asp?lang=e&id=T-REC-H.265-201802-I!!PDF-E&type=items)

Comment: Его разбор описывается в Annex B

Comment: @VTT чей именно? Если разбор h.265\hevc стандарта, то я ничего не нашёл там про NAL unit'ы